# jquery $ selector to apply only to template scope (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, jquery-selectors

I'm generating a template multiple times in the same page, however a function of this template's controller will work on the whole page. How can make sure it only works within the respective template scope?

In this example, when the user clicks a small div, its content it will travel to another div. How does this work? I select the clicked div with a specific class name using jquery and append it to the div it should travel to. However, as I'm calling this template multiple times, the function will select all classes in the page with that same class name, instead of just the template scope.

How can I make it that the selector will only look into the template's scope?

Here's the template:

```
<div ng-controller="templateController">
      <div class="source">
        <div ng-repeat="item in info">
            <div class="content" data-value="{{item.ID}}">{{item.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both" />
    <div class="receiver"></div>
    <div>      
</div>
```

And here's the controller with some jquery functions:

```
angular
  .module("demo")
  .controller("templateController", ["$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout) {
            $scope.info = [
            {
                name: "john",
                ID: 1
            },
            {
                name: "Edward",
                ID: 0
            },
            {
                name: "Carl",
                ID: 2
            }
        ];

        $timeout(function () {
            $(".source .content").click(function () {
                console.log("leaving source");
                $(this).appendTo($(".receiver"));
            })
        });

        $timeout(function () {
            $(".receiver .content").click(function () {
                console.log("leaving receiver");
                $(this).appendTo($(".source"));
            })
        });
```

I also would like to travel back to its original container (as shown in the second function but seems to not be working), but it only travel in one direction.

**Here's a simple plunk with the whole code so you can see it work and see what's wrong**

[enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/TF9xazyCOHV0HuyvTbZ4?p=preview)

Thank you

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Angular is almost always a bad idea.  If you rework you controller to use `ng-click` You can remove the need for jQuery and also the use of `$timeout()`

Comment: your code for removing seems not to work, but you can achieve this with wrapping your `source` and `receiver` in a div with a class (here `myParent`) and do something like this: `var target = $(this).parents(".myParent").find(".receiver"); $(this).appendTo(target);`.

Comment: notes: even if jqlite is in angular, Mark Coleman's comment is valid. For the removing, it's probably because the elements are not in the `receiver` div when click functions are bound. You should check on how to add click functions on dynamically created elements

Comment: @Kaddath I'm trying to use pure JS but it still selects on elements on the page. I already opened a new question

Comment: For a simple thing like what you are trying, you can keep jQuery, using pure JS is not really much better, what Mark Coleman was saying is that you should stick to proper Angular methods to manupilate the DOM, as there can be bad interactions with jQuery's way and the way Angular does things. My advice is do it working with jqlite first if you know it, when it works, try then to keep the same logic with replacing by angular methods if they exist (after all, there is a reason why jqlite is integrated in angular)